# TextArea Field Component of Redux Form Weird Behavior?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I've got some weird behavior going on my posts/new page. When I click inside Content text area input (which is a Field component of Redux Form), a white blank box appears at the top-left of the screen, then again to the top-middle, then inserts itself inside the content text area. I'm using CSS Modules (not sure if that's relevant). This behavior only occurs on the Google Chrome browser and not on Mozilla Firefox. Any help is appreciated.

https://blogaboutit.herokuapp.com/posts/new

https://github.com/KenAustria/BlogAboutIt

Comment: Doesn't happen for me on Chrome.

Comment: @Mrchief Ok, thanks for checking.